# How do I connect to a Azure Worker Role with tcp endpoint? Tech help needed with Tcp and Azure

Tags: c#, azure, tcp

I created a worker role in visual studio and deployed it to Azure.  Azure shows it is running on my staging.

On my cloud services screen there is a URL for the service, but that doesn't seem to do anything when I ping it or just navigate there.  I get:

This webpage is not available

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I wrote the following code to try and access the service through a TcpClient:

```
    string ip = "http://mysite.cloudapp.net";
    int port = 10;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    try
    {
        client.Connect(ip, port);  // This line throws the error.

        if (client.Connected)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.Warn(ex.Message);
    }
```

On client.Connect(ip, port) There is an error that says 
**Message = "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"**

My WorkerRole has the following Run method (copied from an online tutorial i believe).

```
public override void Run()
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("wr is running");


    TcpListener listener = null;

    try
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["myEndpoint"].IPEndpoint);
        listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        listener.Start();
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        Trace.Write("Echo server could not start.", "Error");
        return;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, listener);
        connectionWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Finally in my csdef my endpoint appears like so:

```
<InputEndpoint name="myEndpoint" protocol="tcp" port="10" localPort="10" />
```

I'd like to get the connection talking back and forth.

Comment: How is the "myEndPoint" endpoint declared in your csdef file?

Comment: I have added that information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that I could use the url, but apparently using the ipaddress listed on the azure portal on my service page, under the Input Endpoints (kind of obvious).  I did the following:

```
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("13.71.112.31");
    int port = 10;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    try
    {
        client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
            if (client.Connected) // now true
            {
```

I used this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh285885?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "http:" from the value of the "ip" variable? You want the IP that address points to, but aren't bound to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: I have successfully connected in code by switching the string ip to a IpAddress based on the ip.  I had tried using the IP before but got the same errors, and I thought that the url and the IP would be interchangable.  I'll add an answer to show what I did for future generations.