# azure tcp cloud service unable to connect

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-cloud-services

I have deployed a Worker Role in a azure cloud service, but I cannot connect to it. 
The cloud service has the following definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="classificationCloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WorkerRole name="classificationWorker" vmsize="Small">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
    </Certificates>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Input" protocol="tcp" port="2000" localPort="2000" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

This service uses a TcpListener to listen for incoming connections.

```
IPEndPoint ep = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Input"].
TcpListener listener = null;
try
{
    listener = new TcpListener(ep);
    listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("starting server on {0}:{1}", ep.Address.ToString(), ep.Port));
    listener.Start();
}
catch(SocketException e )
{
    Console.WriteLine("unable to start server", e.Message);
    return;
}
```

The logs for this program show a different IP than the public IP for the cloud service. But this might be because of load balancing?

Anyway, I cannot connect to the deployed instance and I am having a hard time figuring out why.
I have tried accessing the instance using the public IP of the cloud service and the host segment of the URL, but both of these result in a connection timeout.

The cloud service does report the port as an input endpoint next to the rdp port. RDP connection are working fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did u already check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097016/how-do-i-connect-to-a-azure-worker-role-with-tcp-endpoint-tech-help-needed-with

Comment: Yes. The asker in the link uses the http:// protocol prefix, which I do no use and the error message is different. The asker gets a NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error and I get a connection timeout.

Comment: connection timeout is due to the fact that it tried to connect to that endpoint and it could not do so. what is your requirement? is this tcp listener your only option? did you explore queues?

Comment: Yes but it should be able to connect. The same instance exposes the RDP port and i am able to connect to it using [WorkerName].cloudapp.net:3389. Netstat even shows my application listening on port 2000 and I can connect to it locally on the VM. However another application outside of Azure cannot reach the application for some reason. The application receives an image from another application. processes it and sends it to another application. Latency should be minimal so that's why I did not use a queue

Comment: You can try the option of uploading the images to blob storage and then process from there.

Comment: @Aravind thank you for Your help. The issue seemed to be the firewall configuration at the place I am working. I am just a temp so I did not know that outgoing connections to ports other than 80 and 443 where not allowed. I changed the port to 443(as I am planning to use tls) and it fixed the issue for me. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: ok cool. You can always explore queues, blobs etc to decouple the modules and it will be helpful in the longer run.

Comment: Yes I will look into that. For now this will work, but it is definitely something to consider for the future